# get row number of an NSManagedObject in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

i want to know if there is a function in core data to get the row number of a `NSManagedObject` with a specific id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no row number. Don't think in terms of tables, it's an (unordered) object store. The data is often backed in an SQLite store, but not necessarily.

If you need to specify some ordering then you should store and maintain your own `order` attribute on the entity and use that.